# PHP - Writing data to a new file if the file exists and call each line of the generated file in a foreach loop

Tags: php

I have a piece of PHP code as follows:

```
$write_URLs = fopen("links/WriteURLs.txt", "w");
foreach ($list_URLs as $htmlLink) {
    GetURLs ($htmlLink);
    foreach ($URLs as $URL) {
    fwrite($write_URLs, $URL ."\n");
    }
}
fclose($write_URLs);
```

Above code writes the URLs on `links/WriteURLs.txt` on every execution and so the `WriteURLs.txt` file can not save the results of the previous execution.

The problem is that I want to check if `links/WriteURLs.txt` exists, then start to write the URLs on a new file, such as `links/01-WriteURLs.txt`, `links/02-WriteURLs.txt`, ... . After that I want to start reading the URLs from the generated file (i.e. not all files, only the one which is generated in the last step) `links/WriteURLs.txt`, `links/01-WriteURLs.txt`, `links/02-WriteURLs.txt` or ..., and echo the `HELLO WORLD` foreach `URL`. Below you can see the incomplete version of the code that I tried to develop. Could you please help me how to solve this problem? thanks

```
$i = 1;
$write_URLs = fopen("links".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. $i. "-WriteURLs.txt", "w");
if(file_exists($write_URLs)) {
    fclose($write_URLs);
    $new_write_URLs = fopen("links".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. $i++. "-WriteURLs.txt", "w");
} else {
    foreach ($list_URLs as $htmlLink) {
        GetURLs ($htmlLink);
        foreach ($URLs as $URL) {
        fwrite($new_write_URLs, $URL ."\n");
        }
    }    
}
fclose($new_write_URLs);
$trimmed = file(???????????, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
foreach ($trimmed as $URL) {
    echo "Hello World";
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason to not use a database?

Comment: Not really need a database, just saving the links to files would be enough for my purpose,

Comment: Even still, take a look at [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) which is literally perfect for these types of situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'd like to read the data from the text file you just finished writing, you could simply keep track of the name of the file you are working with and then use it later during the read, like this:

```
$i = 0;
do {
  $filename = "links".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $i++ . "-WriteURLs.txt";
} while (file_exists($filename));

$write_URLs = fopen($filename, "w");

foreach ($list_URLs as $htmlLink) {
      $URLs = GetURLs ($htmlLink);
      foreach ($URLs as $URL) {
      fwrite($write_URLs, $URL ."\n");
    }
}    

fclose($write_URLs);
$trimmed = explode("\n",file_get_contents( $filename ) );
foreach ($trimmed as $URL) {
    echo "Hello World";
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Actually what I want is: 1) Write the URLs to a new file, 2) Then read the URLs from the new file which is generated in the previous step (not reading the data from all files),

Comment: I tried to make the question more clear, please review the question and let me know if you need more info,

Comment: thanks for your answer, I got these two errors: 1) Warning: file_exists() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in..., 2) Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in...

Comment: The problem is that it writes on the same file `1-WriteURLs.txt` and also it doesnt echo `"Hello World"`

Comment: I updated my answer to fix an obvious bug and also to work for an arbitrary number of script executions. If you continue to have problems with the script please try to fix first and respond with specific issues, output, errors, what you tried, etc.